# Javascript Functions/ innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, innerhtml

So I'm trying to create a function that when the user clicks on a button or whereever I use the onclick method my problem is I have zero IDEA why my function won't work. I'm like 90% sure it worked yesterday and all I did was turn on my macbook......So I can get document.........innerHTML to work abstractly or in a void....but when I added it to this function it stopped working....I'm sure I did something I'm just not sure what.

```
const insurances = ["amica", "travelers","national general","infinity","cincinatti"];
```

Honestly the only thing I can think that I changed was I made the insurance array a const instead of defining that inside the function but I can't imagine that's my issue.

```
   function cashBack1() {
    var amount=1;
    var statement = "Congratulations you just qualified for up to!! $";
    var insurance= document.getElementById('insurance').value;

    insurance = insurance.toLowerCase;

    amount = !insurances.includes(insurance) ? "$200" : "$300";

    alert("");
    document.getElementById('lilDiv').innerHTML = statement + amount;
  }
```

My second problem is I can't get my and or statements right.....if you notice

```
amount = !insurances.includes(insurance)? "200" :"$300";
```

I'm attempting to get it to an if statement but I started following vs code's suggestions lol. Here's the original version of the function

```
    function cashBack() {
      var amount=1;
      var statement = "Congratulations you just qualified for up to!! $";
      var insurance= document.getElementById('insurance').value;
      insurance = insurance.toLowerCase;
      if(!insurances.includes(insurance)){
      amount = "$200";
      }else {
      amount = "$300";
    } 
    alert("");//I added this alert just to see if it's making down to this part of the code..
             // It's not......
    document.getElementById("lilDiv").innerHTML = statement + amount;
     }
```

So I guess in conclusion this is a double part question. I need help in properly forming my if statement so I can get it to check if the user entered on of the target companies and they receive 300 cash back shown in an empty div.....if it isn't it should state that they receive 200 cash back. Help!
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Here's the HTML This isn't a real project I'm just going through a textbook trying to learn the language before I take the class next..currently i'm only in a basic web development course on HTML-5 and CSS, so forgive me

```
    <body>
    <div id="top1" class="flex-box-container-1">
  <header>
    <h1>CASH BACK GLASS</h1>
  </header>
    </div>
    <div  id="main1" class="flex-box-container-1" >
        <div class="col-3" >
  <nav id="key"> <!--it's better to create function to change color then to 
  keep typing it-->
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getOne();">Get A 
  Windshield</a></li>  
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"  id="getSome" 
  onmouseout="changeBlue('getSome')" onmouseover="changeRed('getSome');" 
  onclick="offerHelp();" >Get Some Help</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#textA"> Leave A Message</a> </li>
  </nav>
  <button id = "button2" onclick = "changeFont();" class="btn- 
 block">Enlarge Doc Text</button>
  <button id="button1" onclick="makeBig();" onblur="makeSmall();" class="btn-outline-dark">Enlarge Nav</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="addList();" class="btn-outline-primary">Do This</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
<img src="windshield.jpeg"  id="photos" onmouseover="changePic('photos','money.jpeg');" onmouseout="changePic('photos', 'windshield.jpeg');">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-box-container-1" id="info" >
        <form onsubmit="msg();">
            <h3>Enter Your Contact Info</h3>
<label for = "fName">First:</label>
<input id="fName" type="text" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" onblur="this.style.background='white';" required>
<br>
<label for = "lName">Last:</label>
<input id = "lName" type = "text" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" onblur="this.style.background='white';" required>
<br>
<label for = "phone">Cell:</label>
<input id = "phone" type="tel" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" onblur="this.style.background='white';" required>
<br>
<label  for="insurance">Insurance:</label>
<input type="text" list="bigPay" id="insurance" onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" onblur="this.style.background='white';"  name="insurance">
<datalist id="bigPay">
<option value="Amica">Amica</option>
<option value="Travelers">Travelers</option>
<option value="Nation General">Nation General</option>
<option value="Nationwide Private Client">Nationwide Private Client</option>
<option value="Infinity">Infinity</option>
<option value="Cincinatti">Cincinatti</option>  
</datalist>
<br>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Appointment date</legend> 
    <label for = "date">When?</label>
    <input id = "date" type="date"  onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" onblur="this.style.background='white';" required>
    <label for = "time">Time?</label>
    <input id="time" type="time"  onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" onblur="this.style.background='white';" required>
    <label for = "address">Where?</label>
    <input id="address" type="text"  onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onclick="this.style.background='yellow';" onblur="this.style.background='white';" required>
  <br>
    <label for = "zip">Zip?</label>
    <input id="zip" type="text"  onmouseover="this.style.background='red';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onblur="fillCity();" onclick="this.style.background='white';" required>
  <label for = "city">City?</label>
  <input id=city type="text">
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id = "bottom" class="flex-box-container-1">
<div class="col-2">

    <label id="labelB" for="textA">Leave A Message</label>
    <textarea id="textA" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onmouseover="this.style.background='purple';" onblur="this.style.background='white';" onclick="cashBack();" name="textA" size="60" rows="4";></textarea>

</div>
</div>
<!--Perhaps my favorite thing is making things appear -->
<div class="flex-box-container-1"  id="lilDiv">
</div>
<div id="para1" class="flex-box-container-1">
<p id="para2">I know it's hard to find an autoglass company you can trust to install your windshield in a professional and responsable manner.
    here at <strong>Cash Back Glass</strong> we strive to match you with a top Auto Glass Company who pays you top dollar to replace <em>Your</em>
    windshield. We schedule mobile appointments at your home or place of business. Our Techs have years of experience and each shop that
    we do business with has been in business for a minimum of 5 years.
</p>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<script src="javascript.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `insurance.toLowerCase` -> `toLowerCase` is a function and not property. It should be `insurance.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Could you post the HTML code, please?

Comment: I edited it to include my HTML for you...